# mongoexport with -f fields flag including all fields without listing one by one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a mongoexport command like this:

```
mongoexport -h mydb-a1.mlab.com:myport -d mydbname -c myCollection -u username -p password -o fileName.csv --csv -f _id,wayTooManyAdditionalFieldsToMakeCommaSepList
```

What is the command to just export your data with every available field?

Comment: Use --fieldFile

Comment: Then I have to list out all of the fields in a file which sort of defeats the purpose I'm after.